# Finding centroids for icosahedral gnomonic projection?

Tags: coordinate-system, centroids, d3

I've been trying to create an icosahedral gnomonic projection, like [this example](https://www.jasondavies.com/maps/airocean/) by Jason Davies or [this one](http://www.progonos.com/furuti/MapProj/Normal/ProjPoly/projPoly3.html) (the Fisher projection). The method that I initially used was using the centroid of each face of the icosahedron as the tangent point for projecting onto each face. Having oriented my projection so that the poles were at vertices, I found that the centroids would be at +-47.71 degrees latitude ((atan(1/2) + atan(1/2) + 90)/3) every 72 degrees longitude for the triangles touching the poles, and at +-8.86 degrees (atan(1/2)/3) for the other 10 faces.

However when I tried constructing it with these values, nothing aligns. I noticed that my regions were not the same as the ones in the examples, so I fudged with my centroid points, and I found that +-53 degrees and +-11 degrees more or less makes everything align. However, I have no idea where these numbers come from. I'm assuming that my method of using the centroids of the faces of the icosahedron is wrong. So my question is, how do I actually calculate these numbers/why do they work?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean precisely by "nothing aligns," but you give some clues. Icosahedral faces are triangles. Thus a face centered at a pole must have only *three* neighbors rather than the five you describe (at "every 72 degrees longitude"). The centers of the icosahedral faces are the vertices of its dual dodecahedron, whose coordinates [are reported by Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dodecahedron%20vertex%20coordinates), *inter alia* (but it needs to be rotated to a pole). Did you notice the Jason Davies example does not center the poles within their faces?

Comment: @whuber I meant that the edges of the projection on each triangular face do not align with the projection on adjacent faces. They are close, but borders are slightly off. The faces are not centered at poles, the poles are at vertices. There are five triangles that share each vertex, which is what I meant by the five neighbors. Yes, I did notice that about Jason Davies example, but it shouldn't matter which way the icosahedron is aligned with the map itself does it (other than obviously different portions of the map being distorted). I aligned the poles with vertices for simplicity's sake.

Comment: @whuber The coordinates you gave me from Wolfram Alpha totally solve my problem though... the centers I was taking were indeed incorrect, and the dodecahedron coordinates correspond to the angles I approximated. Do you want to submit an answer so I can checkmark it?